# I've tried to change a branch but I aborted before it ended, now I have a lot of unstaged files

Tags: git, git-branch

After the many unstaged files I've done `git stash save --keep-index` and now I have a lot of empty folders from the other branch. Now everything is messed up.

How to undo and only have the correct folders from my branch?

Comment: What does git status show?

Comment: On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git clean -fd

Git only store files in its object store so if the directories are empty they will be removed.

See the [`git-clean`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) docs for more information.

Comment: Anyway an aborted operation shouldn't undo all the mess it does by default?